# SEO con Wordpress, Busqueda en Google

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-search-console

Tengo una duda, resulta que cuando busco mi web en google "site:misitio.com" aparece bien pero cuando le agrego el www ya no. Hice la prueba con otras páginas y aparecen de las dos maneras, no entiendo por qué la mia no. Si alguien me puede iluminar por favor, se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: en el search console verifica que esté definida la "propiedad" www dentro del dominio correspondiente, luego en wordpress fijate si tenes un plugin de seo y la url del sitio está definida "con www" debe haber un option de setear las url canonicas para armar el sitemap.xml ( apache tambien debería contar con el redireccionamiento de "sin www" a "con www" ) si el wordpres no está configurado "con www" google no sabe que son lo mismo ( ni cuales son las url canonicas )